# Selection Sort Behavior With Duplicates

Tags: algorithm, sorting, computer-science, selection-sort

How does selection sort handle duplicate values in arrays? I'm having a hard time finding the answer online.

If I have an array like [8, 4, 7, 3, 9, 3] then which index will selection sort choose to swap with on the first pass of the array?

The 3rd index or the 5th index?

Answer (score 1):

Although your specific question about swapping in `3` is easy to answer, a more general version of it is not easy, because selection sort is not *stable*.

Classic implementation will pick `3` at the third index, because the condition for picking the next element to swap is

```
if (a[i] < a[iMin])
```

Once the first `3` is swapped into position 0, the second `3` at index five will not be selected.

The condition implies that the earliest duplicate will be selected according to the arrangement before the current pass of the algorithm. This arrangement may not be the same as the initial arrangement of the elements, though.

As far as duplicates further down the selection process go, there is no guarantee, because a smaller number may be swapped in ahead of them.

For example, in this initial arrangement

```
[3, 3, 1]
```

the `3` at index zero will be picked last, because the first iteration will move it all the way to the end of the array.

Answer (score 0):

It is implementation dependent. 
Usually, however, a loop will start to scan from left to right and will get the first `3`.

But how I say thare is not a standard.

This is a possible implementation according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort):

```
procedure SelectionSort(a: list to sorts);
  for i = 1 to n - 1
    posmin ← i
    for j = (i + 1) to n
      if a[j] < a[posmin]
        posmin ← j
    tmp ← a[i]
    a[i] ← a[posmin]
    a[posmin] ← tmp
```